# Sandbox any file access on linux

Tags: linux

Is there a program that could sandbox any file access from another program in LInux?

The equivalent of what I want in Windows are: [Sandboxie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandboxie).

I intended to use it to trace any files accessed/changed when I run a program on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be case where [unionfs](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/project-unionfs.html) might be useful.  With unionfs, you should be able to mount things in such a way to treat the primary filesystems as read-only and redirect all file writes/modifications into another directory or filesystem.  This is the tool commonly used on livecds to save changes to a USB stick or other storage device.

Another option if you are using LVM and you have free extents would be to take a snapshot.  Run your program, then compare everything on your filesystem against what was within the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strace` to monitor what a program is doing. Limit the listed operations with `-e trace=file` and see the man page for the program. Note however, that the list will include *all* file operations, including the ones to read shared libraries.

Beside that, you can look into the `inotify` infrastructure of the kernel which is more usable for extended operations, as `strace` is mainly a debugging tool.